# Как вывести строки, содержащие конкретную букву? Python

Tags: python

Помогите, пожалуйста, найти ошибку. Нужно вывести строки, содержащие букву "ё". При этом условия:

1. Разрешается ввод только через input.txt.
2. Используйте .filter() и lambda-функции.
3. Примените метод readlines().
4. Если буквы "ё" нет в строке - на экран ничего выводить не нужно.
5. Строку необходимо выводить ровно в том виде, в котором она находится во входном файле (заглавная буква остаётся заглавной, строчная - строчной).

Моё решение:

```
with open ('input.txt', 'r', encoding = 'UTF-8') as f:
  text = f.readlines()
  text2 = list(filter(lambda s: 'ё' in s.lower(), text))
  for i in text2:
      print(i)
```

Скорее всего, появились лишние пустые строки, как можно их убрать?

Текст, из которого нужно вывести строку:

`input.txt`

```
В лесу родилась ёлочка,
В лесу она росла,
Зимой и летом стройная, зеленая была.
```

Comment: "Скорее всего появились" или действительно появились?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется лишних строк не появляется, а все дело в дополнительном переводе каретки.
Попробуйте вот так:

```
print(i, end='')
```

Грубо говоря, у вас идет два перевода каретки `\n\n`

1. `\n` от чтения из файла.
2. `\n` от самого принта.

`end=''` - удалить лишний перевод каретки и вы получите ожидаемый результат.

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое за подробное объяснение, теперь код работает правильно!:)

Comment: Рад был помочь, успехов!)